# Сохранение переменных в куки и последующее их получение

Tags: javascript

Нужно чтобы браузер запоминал переменные в которых хранятся общее количество денег, купленные апгрейды и тд (Делаю подобие кликера, никак не могу разобраться с куки) Какой максимально простой способ это сделать без перелопачивания кода?

Comment: Лучший вариант для браузера - это localStorage  https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Немного некорректно задал вопрос, у меня есть переменная, допустим X, в результате действий пользователя она изменилась, как сохранить текущее ее состояние и при следующем заходе вернуть его, максимально просто( пример кода)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В идеале к таким APP лучше использовать localstorage и хранить в браузере, и jquery подключать только себе дороже выйдет.

Answer (score 0):

Когда то надо было на клиенте работать с куками и сильно помог jQuery плагин - [jQuery Cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)

Чтобы создать куку нужно просто написать слудющее:

```
$.cookie('name', 'value');
```

Чтобы прочитать:

```
$.cookie('name');
```

Больше примеров смотрите по ссылке, очень простой и удобный плагин

Answer (score 0):

@Lspewz как пример со счетчиком времени:

Работает тут: https://jsfiddle.net/26ykbm68/

```
if(localStorage['count'] != null) {
  count = parseInt(window.localStorage['count']);
}

setInterval(function() {
  $("#count").html(count);
  window.localStorage['count'] = count;
  count++;
}, 1000);

$("#clear").on("click", function() {
  window.localStorage['count'] = null;
  count = 0;
});
```